# How to calculate difference between 2 times in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to calculate difference between 2 times.
But it is not working as I expected.

e.g: In the following photo

> 1. current Time
> 2. item created Time
> 3. current Time converted to millisecond
> 4. created Time converted to millisecond
> 5. current - created (millisecond)

[image]

As shown image, I expected the difference 17h 19min 27s. But it gave me 5h 19min 27s. (Just 12 hours difference)

I am not sure that is AM(PM) problem or Time zone problem. I used following method.

```
<Text red>{dayjs(new Date().getTime()).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')}</Text>
<Text red>{dayjs(new Date(`${item.created_at.slice(0, 10)}T${item.created_at.slice(11, 19)}`).getTime()).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')}</Text>
<Text red>{new Date().getTime()}</Text>
<Text red>{new Date(`${item.created_at.slice(0, 10)}T${item.created_at.slice(11, 19)}`).getTime()}</Text>
<Text red>{new Date().getTime()-new Date(`${item.created_at.slice(0, 10)}T${item.created_at.slice(11, 19)}`).getTime()}</Text>
```

How can I get exact difference? In a word, `new Date().getTime()` is not working as I expected.

Answer (score 2):

I ll suggest u to use [date-fns library](https://date-fns.org/v2.16.1/docs/differenceInMilliseconds)

```
var differenceInMilliseconds = require('date-fns/differenceInMilliseconds')
differenceInMilliseconds(dateLeft, dateRight)
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I get expected effect without using specific library ?

Comment: `function dateDiffInHours(date1, date2) {
    return Math.round((date2-date1)/(1000*60*60));
}
var daysDiff=dateDiffInDays(new Date('December 21, 2019 03:24:00'), new Date('December 25, 2019 03:24:00'));
But i ll suggest you to this library.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Let me try. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can also try `moment` if third party is an option for you

Comment: Yes, but if you compare the size of the library I guess fns is smaller than that.

Answer (score 1):

This way I am getting the correct value.

```js
const printRemainingTime = (t2) => {
  const t1 = new Date().getTime();
  let ts = (t1-t2.getTime()) / 1000;

  var d = Math.floor(ts / (3600*24));
  var h = Math.floor(ts % (3600*24) / 3600);
  var m = Math.floor(ts % 3600 / 60);
  var s = Math.floor(ts % 60);

  console.log(d, h, m, s)

}

printRemainingTime(new Date("2020-11-26T06:29:33"));
```

See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-xqdk64

Comment: t1 is not static. That must be current date. So that is dynamic.

Comment: Ok, let me try with current date.

Comment: This is working well in the browser.

const t2 = new Date("2020-11-26 06:29:33").getTime();

But not working on React Native. I don't know why. what is this reason?

<Text>new Date("2020-11-26 06:29:33").getTime()</Text>  :  Not working

Comment: Are you getting any error? you are missing {} here <Text>{new Date("2020-11-26 06:29:33").getTime()}</Text>

Comment: It's my typo.  I I added curly brackets, but also not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225174/discussion-between-lissettdm-and-satelbill).